# Firebase storage - inaccessible from the Philippines?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, storage

I'm using Firebase storage buckets to host some files.  The bucket itself is in the US region, and it seems to be accessible from anywhere in the world - except, earlier in the week a user from the Philippines showed me that no image would load (on the web, as well as the app, and it was this that led me to think it was geo-related).  We flipped on the VPN to be in the US, and the images started to load... so I'm confused, are there geo-restrictions on storage buckets, and is there a way we can know of it?  Could this be some other issue if anyone else has encountered something like it?

Comment: I heard there was a problem with DNS in "Globe Telecom" ISP. You can try to use DNS 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 - might help and fill the bug for firebase here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs

Comment: Seeing similar issues. Did you ever find a solution to this @watermelon_hippo?

Comment: From way back when, the problem fixed itself and was likely just something in the Philippines

Comment: This question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the Firebase support team and they sent me this:

"We have received similar reports with some ISPs (PLDT) and one of their subsidiaries (Smart communications) in the Philippines. However since the issue is caused by something outside the Google network, there is nothing much we can do. Would you mind trying to try using another network to test other ISPs?

So far, I have created an internal escalation for measurement purposes and to see if there is something that we can do to help, but the general recommendation is to report this directly to the ISP, a couple of other developers have reached out to them and they are waiting for a response, but I think that pushing harder could help here."

I still haven't fixed the issue on my part though.

Comment: UPDATE:

Since we could not wait for the Firebase Team or the ISPs to work on this, we decided to back up the images from Google Cloud Storage to our local storage and then have it uploaded on our existing cPanel Storage. We then linked our codes into it instead of Google Cloud Storage. It works fine now.